# htpasswd protecting wrong directory

Tags: .htaccess

I setup htaccess in combination with htpasswd to protect only two subdirectories of the root directory and at first it worked fine but suddenly it's asking for a username and password at the root directory (aka homepage website).

My tree view:`

```
/website (root)
   /cms
   /crm
   /email
```

Now I protected the CMS and CRM directories with htaccess and htpasswd which worked fine until now.

.htpasswd file:

```
user:hashed_pass
```

.htaccess file:

```
AuthName "Welcome/auth text"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Comment: Do you want to remove password protection for the root dir?

Comment: Yeah because the root dir is the main website which should (obviously) be publicly available

Comment: Where is the htaccess located?

Comment: If you see the three view I posted, it's both in the CMS and CRM folder